# Add style to subitem in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have created a wordpress menu with some subitems in it.The style for all the items is almost same except that one of the subitem has  a different class(or style).In the static version that particular item was given a special class to give style.But now its style is same as that of the other menu items.Note that not all the subitems has that particular class just one or two.

```
         <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'nav' ) ); ?>
```

I use wordpress theme twentythirteen.Any idea?

Comment: You can add class to menus or submenus. Go to appearance -> menu-> screen options available on the top right corner in your dashboard. Then open screen options, you see CSS Classes, check that and you'll be able to add class to menu or submenu.

Comment: I have added it.but it makes no difference

Comment: You can use Jquery UI.

Comment: can you give us the test link?